# Memory leaks when generating dispatch source timer events

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-leaks, grand-central-dispatch

We are using dispatch queues to generate timer events. Following is the code which does the task:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
if (!timer) return self;
dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), interval * NSEC_PER_SEC, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, 
^{
    //Some work…
});
```

This works very well except that when we run the profiler, we see a lot of memory leaks from these methods:

- dispatch_source_create
- dispatch_source_set_timer
- dispatch_source_set_event_handler

We had made sure that timer is released using dispatch_release() method.

Can someone please let us know if there is any mistake we are doing in the code above? And also if you can point out any example of timer event generation, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

[dispatch_source_set_timer(3) Mac OS X Manual Page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_source_set_timer.3.html)

> All timers will repeat indefinitely until
>        dispatch_source_cancel() is called.

How do you call dispatch_source_cancel() and dispatch_release() for the timer?

Dispatch source timer example:

```
dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(
    DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0,
        dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0));

dispatch_source_set_timer(timer,
    dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC),
        DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER, 1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, ^{
    NSLog(@"wakeup!");

    dispatch_source_cancel(timer);
});

dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(timer, ^{
    NSLog(@"canceled");

    dispatch_release(timer);
});

dispatch_resume(timer);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I compared your sample code with mine. It looks almost the same. I do the cancel and release in the dealloc and i can see that being called. For me, the timer events are raised properly and everything is working fine. The problem is, i see memory leaks when i run the profiler.